# FubuMVC: How to configure which ISessionState implementation to use

Tags: fubumvc

I have some trouble making Fubu use my own implementation of ISessionState.

My controller has a constructor that takes an ISessionState argument.

I have tried using StructureMap like so in my global asax

```
FubuApplication.For<ConfigureFubu>().StructureMapObjectFactory(container => 
{
    container.Scan(scanner =>
    {
        scanner.TheCallingAssembly();
        scanner.WithDefaultConventions();
    });

    container
        .For<ISessionState>()
        .Use<MySessionState>();
})
.Bootstrap();
```

Where and how am I supposed to tell Fubu to use MySessionState instead of SimpleSessionState?

Answer (score 0):

@Pingvinen This should work as is. What's happening, exactly? I'm assuming you're getting SimpleSessionState injected instead of your implementation?

Just for kicks, you may try going into your ConfigureFubu class and modifying the services (in the constructor):

```
Services(x => x.ReplaceService<ISessionState, MySessionState>());
```

Comment: When I hit my breakpoint MonoDevelop tells me that my session instance is of type SimpleSessionState, and when I use the Set method it does not hit the breakpoint in my implementation's Set method.

Comment: The replace service thing does not do it for me either. I will try updating my Fubu dlls.